# How to display all available perls in perlbrew?

Tags: perl, perlbrew

I can list all available perls via `perlbrew available`

```
kes@kes-X751SA ~ $ pb available

   perl-5.32.0   
   perl-5.30.3   
   perl-5.28.3   
   perl-5.26.3   
   perl-5.24.4   
   perl-5.22.4   
   perl-5.20.3   
   perl-5.18.4   
   perl-5.16.3   
   perl-5.14.4   
   perl-5.12.5   
   perl-5.10.1   
    perl-5.8.9   
    perl-5.6.2   
  perl5.005_03   
  perl5.004_05   
  cperl-5.29.2   
  cperl-5.30.0   
  cperl-5.30.0-RC1
```

But this list only contain `latest` available perls. For example I did not see from this list currently installed perl from perlbrew

```
kes@kes-X751SA ~ $ which perl
/home/kes/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.24.1/bin/perl
```

I have tried `perlbrew available --verbose` but this is not the `full` list:

```
kes@kes-X751SA ~ $ pb available --verbose

   perl-5.32.0  available from  <https://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.32.0.tar.gz>
   perl-5.30.3  available from  <https://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.30.3.tar.gz>
   perl-5.28.3  available from  <https://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.28.3.tar.gz>
   perl-5.26.3  available from  <https://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.26.3.tar.bz2>
   perl-5.24.4  available from  <https://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.24.4.tar.gz>
   perl-5.22.4  available from  <https://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.22.4.tar.bz2>
   perl-5.20.3  available from  <https://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.20.3.tar.bz2>
   perl-5.18.4  available from  <https://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.18.4.tar.bz2>
   perl-5.16.3  available from  <https://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.16.3.tar.bz2>
   perl-5.14.4  available from  <https://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.14.4.tar.bz2>
   perl-5.12.5  available from  <https://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.12.5.tar.bz2>
   perl-5.10.1  available from  <https://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.10.1.tar.bz2>
    perl-5.8.9  available from  <https://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.8.9.tar.bz2>
    perl-5.6.2  available from  <https://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.6.2.tar.gz>
  perl5.005_03  available from  <https://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl5.005_03.tar.gz>
  perl5.004_05  available from  <https://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl5.004_05.tar.gz>
  cperl-5.29.2  available from  <https://github.com/perl11/cperl/archive/cperl-5.29.2.tar.gz>
  cperl-5.30.0-RC1  available from  <https://github.com/perl11/cperl/archive/cperl-5.30.0-RC1.tar.gz>
  cperl-5.30.0  available from  <https://github.com/perl11/cperl/archive/cperl-5.30.0.tar.gz>
```

Is there an option which displays all available perls?

Comment: Try `perlbrew available --all`

Comment: Well, if it lists 5.24.4, that means 5.24.3, 5.24.2, 5.24.1 and 5.24.0 are also available. There's no point in listing the latter 4.

Comment: Re "*You just say that last digit is not important.*", I didn't say anything of the kind. I said if you know .4 exists, then you know .3, .2, .1 and .0 exists, so there's no point in listing the others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-perlbrew/script/perlbrew#COMMAND:-AVAILABLE):

> Usage: `perlbrew available [--all]`
>
> List the recently available versions of perl on CPAN.
>
> The list is retrieved from the web page
> http://www.cpan.org/src/README.html, and is not the list of *all* perl
> versions ever released in the past.
>
> To get a list of *all perls ever released*, use the `--all` option.

so you can use:

```
$ perlbrew available --all
```

Answer (score 3):

`perlbrew available --all` can be used to list all available releases.

But this isn't actually useful. This will include the following additional versions:

- Development release
  Maybe you want to test your code using the latest dev release.
  It'll be hard to spot in `--all`; you'd be better off visiting [this](https://metacpan.org/release/perl) and clicking the "v" arrow before the version.
- Release candidates
  Maybe you want to test your code using the latest release candidate.
  It'll be hard to spot in `--all`; you'd be better off visiting [this](https://metacpan.org/release/perl) and clicking the "v" arrow before the version.
- Earlier minor versions
  There's no reason to lists these because minor versions monotonously increase from `0`. So if you know minor version .4 exists (from `perlbrew available`), then you know .3, .2, .1 and .0 also exist.

---

That said, the OP suggested in the comments that they actually want a list of *installed* versions.

`perlbrew` doesn't provide a means to get that. The version is usually used as part of the name of the install, so you `perlbrew list` could be used to approximate that.

```
  5.32.0t
  5.32t
* latest
  5.30.2t
  5.30t
  acpcw
  gloomhaven
  5.28.2t
  5.28t
  ...
```

But as you can see, it doesn't always work. I'm currently using something call `latest`, which doesn't get me a version.

To get the actual list, you can use the following:

```perl
use 5.014;
use warnings;

use IPC::System::Simple qw( capturex );
use Sort::Key::Natural  qw( natsort rnatsort );

my $root_dir_qfn = $ENV{PERLBREW_ROOT} // "$ENV{HOME}/perl5/perlbrew";   # "
my $perls_dir_qfn = "$root_dir_qfn/perls";

opendir(my $dh, $perls_dir_qfn)
   or die("Can't open dir \"$perls_dir_qfn\": $!\n");

my %versions;
while (defined( my $name = readdir($dh) )) {
   next if $name =~ /^\./;

   my $perl_dir_qfn = "$perls_dir_qfn/$name";
   eval {
      my $version = capturex("$perl_dir_qfn/bin/perl", "-e", 'print $^V');
      die "Program exited with error ".( $? >> 8 )."\n" if $?;
      push @{ $versions{$version} }, $name;
      return 1;  # No exception.
   }
      or warn("Can't get version for \"$name\": $@");
}

for my $version (rnatsort keys(%versions)) {
   say "$version: " . join(" ", natsort @{ $versions{$version} });
}
```

Output:

```
v5.32.0: 5.32.0t 5.32t latest
v5.30.2: 5.30.2t 5.30t acpcw gloomhaven
v5.28.2: 5.28.2t 5.28t
v5.26.3: 5.26.3t 5.26t
v5.26.1: system
v5.24.4: 5.24.4t 5.24t
v5.22.4: 5.22.4t 5.22t
v5.20.3: 5.20.3t 5.20t
v5.18.4: 5.18.4t 5.18t
v5.16.3: 5.16.3t 5.16t
v5.14.4: 5.14.4t 5.14t
v5.12.5: 5.12.5t 5.12t
v5.10.1: 5.10.1t 5.10t
```

The above program doesn't handle versions of Perl that don't support `$^V`, but that's easy to handle by using `$] < ... ? $] : eval('$^V')`.

The above program could also be modified to group by thread support, arch, etc.